# Switching React component property depending on route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working on my first ever React project and I'm a bit stuck with how to tackle this situation.

The `Header` component supports multiple different themes, which I need to be able to switch depending on the page being displayed. Here is my root component:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Header theme='light' />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' />
                        <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
                        <Route exact path='/clients' component={Clients} />
                        <Route exact path='/services' component={Services} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

The `Header` component can receive a `theme` property (one of `light`, `dark` and `solid`). I want to change this property from inside the components rendered by the routes.

My current thinking is to add a `setHeaderTheme` method to the `App` component and pass this function to the components, but I can't work out a) how to pass additional properties to components via routes and b) if this is even the best course of action.

Answer (score 2):

try passing props to render method from Route to your component Clients, as below:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  setHeaderTheme() {
   //code
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
              <Header theme='light' />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' />
                <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
                <Route exact path='/clients' render={() => <Clients setHeaderTheme={this.setHeaderTheme.bind(this)}/> } />
                <Route exact path='/services' component={Services} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Then, inside Clients you can execute the function from parent by:

```
this.props.setHeaderTheme();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can I just ask a quick follow-up question, where is the best place to set the header theme inside the Clients component? Does the command belong in a lifecycle callback?

Comment: It seems that initially the Header has a default configuration that you will change in Routed component. Once in routed component like Clients you can change Header in a early lifeCycle like componentWillMount() , as you will not change state of Clients components nor seems to have dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To pass additional parameters to components via route by following code

```
<Route path="/abc" render={()=><TestWidget num="2" someProp={100}/>}/>

or

<Route exact path="/abc" render={props => <TestWidget someProp="2" {...props} />} />
```

Then on TestWidget you can access the URL parameters with just `this.props.urlVariableHere`

Kindly have a look on

[Pass props to components](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105)

[React url parameters](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)